# django model field definition for hierarchy, GenericForm

Tags: django, django-models

I want to represent a model hierarchy of categories in django orm.
So f.i. you could have categories such as:

```
TopCategory
    SubCategory1
        SubSubCategory
    SubCategory2
```

This is my field definition, which points to the parent category:

```
class Category(models.Model)
    parentcategory = models.OneToOneField('self', blank = True, null = True)
```

And I use a GenericForm in the view:

```
def detail(request, category_id):   
    categoryInstance = Category.objects.get(pk = category_id)   
    GenericForm = modelform_factory(Category)
    form = GenericForm(instance = categoryInstance)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GenericForm(request.POST, instance = categoryInstance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

This does work, there is only one slight problem.
No category should be allowed to point to itself as a parent.
The form renders a dropdown where all categories are listed however.

I did try something like this in the field definition:

```
limit_choices_to = Q('parentcategory_id' is not id)
```

But that gave me an error.
I could probably check and present an error message to the user, but maybe someone knows another way?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use `ForeignKey`'s `limit_choices_to` attribute, as it can not access instance variables of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/#readme) is recommended for working with hierarchies in django.